# How to covert substring to integer?

Tags: postgresql

I have varchar data then i want to convert it to integer so i can using the number to order my data this is my varchar

`No.SKF.4-04/2021/CBO-ODSP`
`No.SKF.5-04/2021/CBO-ODSP`
`No.SKF.6-04/2021/CBO-ODSP`
`
i want to take the number so i can select order the data

`SELECT varchar from account_information order by CAST(substring(left("NO_SURAT", "length"("NO_SURAT")-17),8)as integer)`

but it show some error

`SELECT CAST(substring(left("NO_SURAT", "length"("NO_SURAT")-17),8)as integer) from account_information`

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: ""

how do i covert substring result to int?

Comment: There are several numbers in your data. Please clarify.

Comment: number after `No.SKF.` and before `-`

Comment: I'd find it simpler to do with a regexp, something like `substring(column from '^No\.SKF\.(\d+)-')::integer`

Comment: The issue you're having is your substring is returning empty string, which fails to cast to an integer. You can do `NULLIF(..., '')` to remove the empty strings, but it implies there's also something wrong with the substring. What happens if you remove the `CAST`, does it return the numbers you want?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding an expensive regular expression, you could use:

```
SELECT CAST(
          substr(
             'No.SKF.5-04/2021/CBO-ODSP',
             8,
             position('-' IN 'No.SKF.5-04/2021/CBO-ODSP') - 8
          ) AS integer
       );

 substr 
════════
      5
(1 row)
```